# What is a counter example for this statement?

Tags: formal-languages

I know this is false, but I don't know any counter example for it:

For languages A and B, If A reduces to B, then B reduces to A.

Comment: "reduces to" means:

Comment: A problem A reduces to a problem B means, If we have a solution for B, then we have a solution for A.

Comment: "reduces to" means that there exists a function $f: \Sigma^* \to \Gamma^* $ such that $ w \in A \Leftrightarrow f(w) \in B $

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter example consider two languages with the alphabet $\{0,1\}$.

$ A = (0|1)^* $ and $ B = 1 $.

There is a reduction function from A to B $f(w) = "1" $.

However we can't create a reduction function from B to A because there is no way to map a non word string in B (like $"0"$) into a nonword string of A because A doesn't have any nonword strings.